# Path to assets in Laravel not works after upload on server

Tags: php, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5.3.16. My created webpage works fine on local but after send to server links like:

`<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/custom.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">`

not works. I know that if I add 'public' to link

`<link href="{{ URL::asset('public/css/custom.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">`

file is loaded and works on server but not on local. I found some advices to change link to be like that:

`<link href="{{ asset('/css/custom.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">`

but it not works too.

I set in

```
'providers' => [
'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
]
```

in

```
'aliases' => [
'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
        'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
    ],
```

in composer.json

```
"require": {

        "laravelcollective/html": "5.3.*"
}
```

and I try

```
{!! Html::style('css/style.css') !!}
```

but it doesnt work too.

What I have to change to load assets properly both on server and locally ?

Comment: dd on app('url'), what does it output?

Comment: After `<?php dd(URL::asset('css/custom.css')) ;?>` is `"https://demo.tiltkomp.pl/css/custom.css"`